# Linux use variable to change file name

Tags: linux, file, rename

I have picked up a folder name like this:

```
fname=${i##*/},
```

Where `i` is the 'runner' in a for loop, btw. Incidently, the `i` is the current directory. Now, I would like to use the `$fname` for renaming an other file. Something like this:

```
mv OLDFILE.Extension $fname.NewExtension
```

How can this be done in linux/bash?

Thanks
jd

Comment: Exactly as you wrote, if I get you right. Did you try it? Maybe with `echo OLDFILE.Extension "$fname".NewExtension`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. But I did:

```
mv OLDFILE.Extension $fname"NewExtension"
```

It worked out well.

jd